# Trying to make a list of paths TypeError: unicode string or integer address expected instead of bytes instance

Tags: python, autoit

I'm fairly new to python and am trying to write out code that can send out a image via an image on my computer but I can only have one, and cant list them out.

```
ExampleList = random.choice(['C:\\Example\\image.jpg', 'C:\\Example\\image.jpg'])
```

And then I used autoit

```
autoit.control_send("Open", "Edit1", examplelist)
```

Then get the error:

> TypeError: unicode string or integer address expected instead of bytes instance

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me. Not seeing the error code you have.
However, python is case sensitive, so the lower and upper cases in your "ExampleList" should be consistent.
The first element of control_send is "title/hWnd/class of the window to access". Where are your sending your image location?

Comment: I'm using it to automate Instagram, and iv'e tried it using with just one path and it worked fine but adding multiple it gives me the error code.
EDIT: You were right about the case sensitive portion it works now! Thank you for the information